# auto variable and register variable -- optimized the same?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, setjmp

I am reading APUE, and when I came to `longjmp` , the question came. Before optimization, both the auto variable and register variable store in memory, after optimization, they store in register, the book says. But when I use `objdump -S a.out`, I found both of them became to immediate operand. So ?

Comment: Using the compiler directly to produce assembler output is usually much simpler. For gcc the option is e.g `-S` instead of `-c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book was just simplifying. Even before optimizing there is no guarantee that variables are realized in memory. The difference between `auto` and `register` is just that you are not allowed to take the address of a `register` variable. The C compiler can do anything that behaves the same as the abstract machine.

That your compiler realizes these variables as immediats is an indication that the values that you have there are small and are compile time constants. So you probably could have declared them `const` or even as `enum` constants in the first place.

Comment: If not allowed to take the address fo a `register` variable , how to get the value of it ? Thank you.

Comment: @znlyj, I am not sure that I understand your question. To get the value of a variable you just use it in an expression as any other variable. What you are not allowed to do is to use the `&` operator to take its address.

Comment: Ok , thanks for your answer. But what do you mean by "ven before optimizing there is no guarantee that variables are realized in memory"?

Comment: @znlyj, I mean that the code that the compiler could decide to put variable in register, immediates (or whatever the future may bring for computer architectures) even without any optimization option or so. The compiler is completely free to realize your program as seems good, as long as it behaves the same as in the abstract machine.

Answer (score 1):

So the program is very simple, and the compilers have gotten much smarter since the book has been written.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So , that's the point? I mean, a bit surprised ,you know.

Comment: Why surprised? What are you actually trying to find out?

Answer (score 0):

So you used a different compiler, maybe on a different machine, probably with different levels of optimization, and you can conclude essentially nothing from this except that the behaviour of compilers varies, which makes it hard to write a text book that is accurate in every detail on all machines for all time.

Comment: Thank you all the same. It seems I need pay more attention to the difference between compiles.